# Is there an algorithm to compute group presentations of or find generators for the centralizer of a matrix in $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algorithms

Let $M \in H \leq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.  Is there an algorithm that computes either matrix generators or even a group presentation for $C_H(M)$ given generators or a presentation of $H$?  Also is $C_H(M)$ necessarily finitely generated if $H$ is?

I realize that you can view $C_H(M)$ as the set of integer solutions of the equations $MAM^{-1} = A$ where $A \in H$, but I wasn't sure how one can find generators.

Edit: We can assume that $H$ has decidable membership problem.  In the context that I am working in, $H$ will be the centralizer of a previous matrix so membership is solvable by the above logic.  I also have no idea if anything even exists in the case $H =  GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: This looks hopeless without some restrictions on $H$. For example, the membership problem in $H$ could be undecidable.

Comment: Derek - I just edited the post in regards to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ itself this is addressed in the answer to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55620/commuting-matrices-in-gln-z) As for arbitrary subgroups, in [some cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167156/center-of-a-finitely-generated-fc-group) they are finitely generated. For reflection group, there is the paper of Daniel Alcock (Reflection centralizers in Coxeter groups), I doubt anything intelligent can be said in general.